# ElasticSearch - if field is null, treat as 0?

Tags: ruby, lucene, elasticsearch

I am using ElasticSearch, and am running into NullPointerExceptions because a field I am basing the score on is NULL for several documents.

How do I make ElasticSearch treat these null fields as 0?

FWIW, I'm using the Tire gem and this is my Ruby code:

```
s = Tire.search "articles" do
            query do
                custom_score :script => "_score < 2 ? 0 : doc['num_likes'].value" do
                   match fields, keyword
                end     
            end               
end
```

Comment: Does null_value in mapping could work for you? See null_value in http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/core-types/

Comment: it absolutely does, but it means I have to reindex it. I'll do that if that's the only alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered I need to do something like this:

```
_score < 2 ? 0 : (doc['num_likes'].empty ? 0 : doc['num_likes'].value)
```

Answer (score 1):

What about a script like :

```
"_score < 2 ? 0 : (doc['num_likes'] == null ? 0 : doc['num_likes'].value)"
```

Does it work?

Comment: I need to use .empty rather than check for null, see below. Thanks for the help though!